# Image not showing in Canvas tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tags, tkinter-canvas

I have a code where I'm using the `create_image()` method of Canvas, I want to use tags to bind the respective methods but when I run the code the image doesn't show up on the canvas.

I made a simple code example to show what I mean:

```
from tkinter import *


class CanvasM(Canvas):
    width = 600
    height = 400

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg='black')

        self.pack(pady=20)

        self.create_an_image(
            file='images/cat-image-no-background/cat.png', x=320, y=180)

        self.tag_bind('imagec', "<ButtonPress-1>", self.press)
        self.tag_bind('imagec', "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.release)
        self.tag_bind('imagec', "<B1-Motion>", self.motion)

      

    def create_an_image(self, file, x, y):
        img = PhotoImage(file)
        self.create_image(
            x, y, image=img, tags=('imagec',))

    def press(self, event):
        print(event.x, event.y)

    def release(self, event):
        print(event.x, event.y)

    def motion(self, event):
        print(event.x, event.y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Holi')
    root.geometry("800x600")

    c = CanvasM(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

It just looks like an empty canvas:
[image: Empty canvas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in `create_an_image()`:

- `img` is a local variable, so it will be garbage collected after exiting the function. So use an instance variable `self.img` instead.
- you need to use `file` option of `PhotoImage()` to specify the filename of the image

```py
    def create_an_image(self, file, x, y):
        # use instance variable self.img instead of local variable img
        # use file option of PhotoImage
        self.img = PhotoImage(file=file)
        self.create_image(x, y, image=self.img, tags=('imagec',))
```

Comment: @David04 If it solves your problem, please consider to accept it as the answer and upvote to show your appreciation.

Comment: I already did it! Thanks!.